# curl: when use "--no-progress-meter" over "-sS"?

Tags: curl, options

About `curl` about to hide the *Progress Meter* I found many answers through *Stack Exchange* branches doing mention of `-s` and `-S` or simply `-sS` where

- `-s` hides the progress meter
- `-S` only shows error messages, it even when `-s` is used

Therefore is suggested work as `-sS`

In some posts were mentioned as a new addition for `curl` about the `--no-progress-meter` option, such as:

- [How do I get cURL to not show the progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21109454/3665178)
- [How to suppress cUrl's progress meter when redirecting the output?](https://superuser.com/a/1569460/1024056)

I read `man`

```
--no-progress-meter
       Option to switch off the progress meter output without muting or otherwise affecting warning and informational messages like --silent does.

       Note that this is the negated option name documented. You can thus use --progress-meter to enable the progress meter again.

       Example:
        curl --no-progress-meter -o store https://example.com

       See also -v, --verbose and -s, --silent. Added in 7.67.0.
```

and [curl ootw: –silent](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/07/13/curl-ootw-silent/) (written by an important curl committer)

But sadly is not clear for me how `--no-progress-meter` works. I thought at a first glance that `--no-progress-meter` is equivalent as `-sS` but - it is not indicated explicitly in the both resources - Therefore my assumption is incorrect.

I did do some experiments:

### Without Error

```
#1
curl https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz -O
# Shows
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8472k  100 8472k    0     0  3500k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 3501k

#2
curl https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz -O -s
# Shows Nothing

#3
curl https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz -O -sS
# Shows Nothing

#4
curl https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.6/binaries/apache-maven-3.8.6-bin.tar.gz -O --no-progress-meter
# Shows Nothing
```

Practically is not clear the difference between `-sS` and `--no-progress-meter` because there is no error.

### With Error

**Error** because the `URL` is incorrect, it only is based in the `https` part

```
#1
curl https -O
# Shows
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: (23) Failed writing received data to disk/application

#2
curl https -O -s
# Shows nothing

#3
curl https -O -sS
# Shows
curl: (23) Failed writing received data to disk/application

#4
curl https -O --no-progress-meter
# Shows
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: (23) Failed writing received data to disk/application
```

Observe `#1` and `#2` are the same

**Question**

- When use `-no-progress-meter` over `-sS`?

If you can share some real examples to understand the difference, it is appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The man page says:

> ```
> -s, --silent
>
>          Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter  or  error  mes‐
>          sages.   Makes  Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask
>          for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect
>          it.
>
>          Use  -S,  --show-error  in  addition  to  this option to disable
>          progress meter but still show error messages.
> ```

So essentially, there are four possible combinations, in order of increasing quietness:

- with no options: display progress meter, warning messages and error messages
- with `--no-progress-meter`: display warning messages and error messages, but not the progress meter. This option provides information if something goes wrong, but is silent if there are no problems.
- with `-sS`: display error messages only, but not the progress meter nor warning messages. Good if you are writing a script and know that something might cause warning messages that are harmless in that particular situation, but still want to show error messages if something unexpected happens.
- with `-s`: be completely silent, no messages at all.

Comment: The situation is clear about when to use and ignore the `warning` messages. Thank You.

Comment: Wondered why the `warning messages` term does not appear explicitly in the documentation.